# Unity RaycastHit2D in Physics2D.Raycast not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and wanna create a 2D game. Now there's a problem.
My problem is, that the third argument (out hit) is not working. Following error has appeared: "Argument 3 may not be passed with the 'out' keyword"

```
Vector3 dir = DirFromAngle(globalAngle);
        RaycastHit2D hit;

        if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, dir, out hit, obstacleMask))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Physics2D.Raycast()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) does not have any "out hit" parameter - you are probably thinking about the 3D version [Physics.Raycast()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) (which can't be used in a 2D game). Do something like this:

```
 RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, dir, float.MaxValue, obstacleMask);
 // If it hits something...
 if (hit.collider != null)
 {
    ...
 }
```